# Is this sequence of concave functions unbounded?

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $h_1, h_2,$ etc. be a sequence of positive real numbers such that
$$\sum_nh_n = \infty.$$
Let $x_1, x_2,$ etc. be a sequence of real numbers in $(0, 1)$.

Let $f_0, f_1,$ etc. be of sequence of functions $[0,1]\to [0,\infty)$. Define $f_0 \equiv 0$ and, for each $n$, let $f_n$ be the smallest concave function such that 
$$f_n(x_n) \ge f_{n-1}(x_n) + h_n$$
and $f_n \ge f_{n-1}$ pointwise. Does the Lipschitz constant of $f_n$,
$$\sup_{x, y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|},$$ necessarily tend to infinity?

**Edit:** 
Prior to this edit, the question was incorrectly formulated as "Does $\sup_x f_n(x)$ necessarily tend to infinity?"

Answer (score 2):

No.
Take $x_n = 2^{1-n}$, $h_1 = 1$ and $h_n = 1/2$ otherwise.
Note that
$ f_n(x) = \min(2^{n-1} x, 1)$.

Comment: Thank you. As you may have guessed, I misstated the problem. I have corrected the statement.